# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google_auth_oauthlib'

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux-mint, google-ads-api

I am trying to run the 'generate_refresh_token.py' file in the authentification folder of the AdWords API.

But when I do `python generate_refresh_token.py` as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/wiki/API-access-using-own-credentials-(installed-application-flow)#step-2---setting-up-the-client-library), I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google_auth_oauthlib'`.

So I try to install the module with `pip install google-auth-oauthlib`, and here is the output:

```
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-oauthlib in /home/$USER/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.2.0)
```

I activate my anaconda3 environment by doing `source activate /home/$USER/anaconda3/envs/$environment_name`. I try to generate the token again with the command above, same error.

Could not find any useful answer or anyone having the same issue with this module. Does anyone have a suggestion I could try?

UPDATE: I have found the error. When I installed the google-auth-oauthlib module via pip, it was installed as a module in the anaconda3 library. But when I run python from the command line, it uses the version from my system, which doesn't have this module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the error. When I installed the google-auth-oauthlib module via pip, it was installed as a module in the anaconda3 library. But when I run python from the command line, it uses the version from my system, which doesn't have this module.

Comment: Upvote for finding your own answer. Another one for publishing it, if I could. Well done!

Answer (score 29):

I had the same issue. Was resolved by using:

> sudo pip install google-auth-oauthlib

the sudo was necessary, not sure why, maybe someone else can eleborate.

Comment: Just an update. Don't use sudo with pip...bad practice there are a bunch of SO threads out there about why you shouldn't.

Basically, best practice is to use pip --user

Comment: Check if it works with just ´pip install --user google-auth-oauthlib`. Do NOT use sudo with pip as you are almost certain to duck your python dist to smithereens.

Answer (score 11):

If you use `conda` instead of `pip`:

```
conda install google-auth google-auth-oauthlib
```

Comment: This one worked like a charm. In my case conda was already installed, if anyone has it installed too, this method seemed to work better for me than the pip method.

Answer (score 4):

I was in a situation where installing using `pip install google-auth-oauthlib` worked, but I was still seeing ModuleNotFoundError you mention above.

I tried the approach of installing via `sudo pip install google-auth-oauthlib`. That didn't work, and I kept seeing `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cli.main`.

If anyone else is in the same boat, I was able to successfully install using `pip3 install google-auth-oauthlib` (oddly enough, `pip3` and `pip` both point to the same location for me: `pip 21.2.4`).

Answer (score 0):

Activate your virtual environment and install the module there.It will works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).