# how do you fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google_auth_oauthlib'?

Tags: python, module, kivy

I am trying to incorporate a google calendar into my kivy app but ran into a problem importing google_auth_oauthlib. I already downloaded it through terminal with and without sudo, so I really have no idea what is going wrong. Thank you for reading :)

```
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery as discovery
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
```

Comment: What OS you are running?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53387781/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-google-auth-oauthlib or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55817076/what-is-the-proper-way-import-python-modules-for-dev-appserver

Comment: I am using macOS Mojave version 10.14.6